# drools rules syntax for nested classes

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

Newbie question on drools. I am trying to access the following java class in the rules file.

```
Class A{
  private String foo;
  private SomeClass B;
  //getter setter for foo and b
}
Class B{
  private String bar;
  private Integer value;
  //getter setter for bar and value
}
```

In the rule file I would like to access the member `bar`.

So far this is what I have:-

```
package demo;
import my.test.A;
import my.test.B;

rule "Rule1"
    when
        $varB : A.B(bar.equals("hello")) 
    then 
        $varB.setValue(1);
        update($varB);
end
```

For the above rule I get this error - `"BuildError: Unable to resolve ObjectType A.B"`. I also tried using `A.getB()` and that did not help either. Any idea what it should be? I am using eclipse drools plugin if that matters.

I have looked at the jboss rules [docs](http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs) but they do not cover the syntax stuff that well. Does anyone know of links where I can look up drools syntax and how tos like above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably better:

```
A(b.bar == "hello", $varB : b)
```

In DRL, `==` means *equals*, not *same*.
With `$varB : b` you do something like `B varB = a.getB();`

Comment: +1: Good to know. Do you know of any good links for studying drools rule syntax?

Comment: You can check the Drools examples for syntax tips.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
$varB : A(B.bar.equals("hello"))
```

Comment: Thanks! How did you know this? Is there a syntax look up link that you know of?

Comment: I don't know drools, I've guessed it :)

Comment: $varB will be of type A in this expression, it won't be of type B.